Как достать переменную из функции
Спросил у пользователя дату и после проверки на валидность записал в словарь. Нужно poluch1 использовать в другом файле как переменную (для проверки дня недели и присвоения определенного значения). Как можно вытянуть её из функции dostal_datu?
@router.message(F.text == 'Узнать расписание по дате')
async def vibore(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Vvod.data)
    await message.answer('Введите дату в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ')
@router.message(Vvod.data)
async def dostal_datu(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    data1 = message.text
    correctdate = None

    for funcs in data1:
            try:
                poluch1 = DT.datetime.strptime(data1, '%d-%m-%Y')
                correctdate = 'Спасибо, дата введена успешно'
                await state.update_data(data1=str(poluch1))
                await message.answer(str(correctdate))
                current_data = await state.get_data()
                await state.clear()
                break
            
            except ValueError:
                correctdate = 'Не верный формат даты, необходимо ДД-ММ-ГГГГ, введите дату еще раз:'
                await message.answer(str(correctdate))


Например, вернув(return) значение переменной из функции

Например, записать в БД и потом оттуда достать. Не очень понятно, какая у вас архитектура приложения.
